# Definition '[Single:'com.example.handlers.SocketHandler']' try to override existing definition koin android

Tags: android, kotlin, dependency-injection, interface, koin

I have an SocketHandler interface and two other classes that implement this interface.
I want to implement this interface in several handlers and inject them by koin.

```
interface SocketHandler {

    fun onReceive(socketResponses: Enums.SocketResponses, callback: (item: String) -> Unit)

}


class ClassAHandlerImpl : SocketHandler, KoinComponent {

    override fun onReceive(
       socketResponses: Enums.SocketResponses, callback: (item: String) -> Unit
    ) {
        ....
    }

}


class ClassBHandlerImpl: SocketHandler, KoinComponent {

    override fun onReceive(
        socketResponses: Enums.SocketResponses, callback: (item: String) -> Unit
    ) {
        ....
   }
}
```

And the Koin module implementation for those classes

```
val handlersModule = module {
    single<SocketHandler> {
        return@single ClassAHandlerImpl()
    }

    single<SocketHandler> {
        return@single ClassBHandlerImpl()
    }

...
}
```

However i get an exception

```
Caused by: org.koin.core.error.DefinitionOverrideException: Definition '[Single:'com.example.handlers.SocketHandler']' try to override existing definition. Please use override option or check for definition '[Single:'com.example.handlers.SocketHandler']'
```

Comment: I don´t know which is the problem because currectly i´m working with dagger, but i ´m goint to give you a clue, search something like named -> https://doc.insert-koin.io/#/koin-core/koin-component?id=retrieving-definitions-with-get-amp-inject to know when is necessary to use the right interface

Answer (score 1):

Koin doesn't know which `SocketHandler` instance to retrieve since it's defined twice in the module.

You should use named parameters:

```
val handlersModule = module {
    single<SocketHandler>(named("SocketHandlerA")) {
        return@single ClassAHandlerImpl()
    }

    single<SocketHandler>(named("SocketHandlerB")) {
        return@single ClassBHandlerImpl()
    }

...
}
```

And then you can inject in your classes:

```
private val socketHandler by inject<SocketHandler>(named("SocketHandlerA"))
```